# AWS Payment Cryptography - import RootCertificatePublicKey throws ValidationException: Provided public key is not a valid X509 certificate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, cryptography, x509certificate

I want to import root certificate - RootCertificatePublicKey in Kotlin using SDK for AWS Payment Cryptography. Despite having certificate in proper format, I receive:
`ValidationException: Provided public key is not a valid X509 certificate`

I have a certificate in string in format:

```
val rootCert = """-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFXjCCA0agAwIB ...<base64cert> ... wK0fe4Teg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----"""
```

code in Kotlin:

```
val importedCert = paymentCryptographyClient.importKey(
        ImportKeyRequest.builder()
                .keyMaterial(
                        ImportKeyMaterial.fromRootCertificatePublicKey(
                                RootCertificatePublicKey.builder()
                                        .keyAttributes(
                                                KeyAttributes.builder()
                                                        .keyAlgorithm(KeyAlgorithm.RSA_4096)
                                                        .keyClass(KeyClass.PUBLIC_KEY)
                                                        .keyModesOfUse(
                                                                KeyModesOfUse.builder()
                                                                        .verify(true)
                                                                        .sign(true)
                                                                        .build()
                                                        )
                                                        .keyUsage(KeyUsage.TR31_S0_ASYMMETRIC_KEY_FOR_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE)
                                                        .build()
                                        )
                                        .publicKeyCertificate(rootCert)
                                        .build()
                        )
                ).build()
)
```

I am receiving error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.paymentcryptography.model.ValidationException: Provided public key is not a valid X509 certificate. (Service: PaymentCryptography, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ef5ca7f5-e980-4fe1-bc5d-867e68f4d63e)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:125)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:82)
```

It is strange, because cert looks to be in proper format. Online parsers reads it properly.